# Boundary effects with scipy.fftconvolve after convolution

Tags: fft, convolution, scipy

I am having some numerical error in my code that propagates continuously, and has to do with the implementation of convolutions in Python; this is kind of struggling my progress and I would really appreciate some advice here.

**THE PROBLEM:** I want to numerically evaluate a convolution integral of two (complex) signals $f*g$ using a Fast Fourier Transform algorithm, so I am using `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`. The two signals are defined over a grid of equally-spaced points "x", and their real and imaginary parts look something like this:
[image]

[image]

where the blue line corresponds to $f[x]$ and the dashed line to $g[x]$, and the first figure represents the real parts. Also, note that the support of both signals is finite, in the sense that the functions do not decay completely to zero at the edges, but rather to very small values. I am using `np.complex128` for the signals.

The problem is I want to get y[x] = ( f*g )[x] so that the function $y[x]$ resulting from the integral is evaluated at exactly the same x-grid points as f and g. Then I evaluating the integral as:

```
y = dx*scipy.signal.fftconvolve( f, g, mode="same" )
```

and I get the following:

[image]

with the real part of $y[x]$ in blue and the orange being the imaginary part. If I understand correctly, using the `mode="same"` on `fftconvolve` should provide precisely the value of the convolution integral on the original grid of points x.

The problem has to do with  the edges; it seems to me these values are some sort of error due to the zero-padding or something similar here. The functions f and g are supposed to decay to 0 at infinity ( actually, f is supposed to decay to 0, and g to a constant value ), however the support of both f and g seems to be much larger than the used grid for this integration. Analytically, one has an infinite range of integration (the limits of the integral are -+ infinity), but here, the largest value of $x$ serves as the limit of integration. As a result, this error propagates in my code leading to instabilities of the solutions at the edges. Can anyone give some advice or method on how to solve these issues?

**EDIT**: Here is a minimal working code of the kind of calculations involved. The signals are given by the components of the F1,F2,F3,F4 arrays, with each individual signal having N_points (same as the grid x). The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

# all signals are given by the arrays F1,F2,F3,F4, which
# have shapes (N_points, 3, 3 ). The components that are
# convolved are the ones in the axes 1,2 of the array, so
# each signal is defined on a grid x of N_points length

a =np.array( [[ -1j, 0.1, 0.0 ],
              [0.1, 0.0, 0.1],
              [0.0, 0.1, -1j]] )

B =100.0*1j*np.identity( 3 )

xmax     = 20*100
N_points = 2001

x    = np.linspace( -xmax, xmax, N_points )

X    = np.zeros(  ( N_points , 3, 3 ) )

for k in range(3):
    X[ :, k,k ] = x 


the_array_to_invert = X - a[ np.newaxis, :, : ] + B[np.newaxis, :, :]    

F1   = np.linalg.inv( the_array_to_invert )
F2   = -1j*( F1 @ F1 )

cc_term  = np.zeros( F1.shape, dtype=np.complex128 )

for k in range(3):    
    cc_term[ :, k,k ] = -2j*np.sign( x )    

# now these two F3 and F4 have discontinuities at x=0 due to the sign function

F3 = F1 @ cc_term @ ( np.conjugate( F1.swapaxes(1,2) ) )
F4 = F2 @ cc_term @ ( np.conjugate( F1.swapaxes(1,2) ) ) + F1 @ cc_term @ ( np.conjugate( F2.swapaxes(1,2) ) )

F4 += F1 @ cc_term @ np.conjugate( F1.swapaxes(1,2) )

# now, we convolve always F1,F3 components against F1,F4
# as an example
dx          = np.abs( x[0]-x[1] ) 
conv_result = dx*fftconvolve( F1[ :, 0, 0 ], F4[ :, 1, 1 ] , mode="same"  )

import matplotlib.pyplot as pyt

pyt.plot( x, np.real( F1[ :, 0, 0 ] ) )
pyt.plot( x, np.real( F4[ :, 1, 1 ] ) )

pyt.plot( x, np.imag( F1[ :, 0, 0 ] ) )
pyt.plot( x, np.imag( F4[ :, 1, 1 ] ) )

pyt.plot( x, np.real( conv_result ) )
pyt.plot( x, np.imag( conv_result ) )
```

I have taken, for instance, the (0,0) component of F1 to convolve with the (1,1) component of F4, but the real calculation involves more combinations of components. To illustrate the problem, here is what I obtain for the signals; the real parts of the signals are:
[image]

so note that Re(g)=0 in this specific example, whereas the imaginary parts of the signals are:
[image]

You can see the Im(g) has a discontinuity at x=0, so there is a little jump in that region. What we want is `f*g`, and I obtain for the Re(f*g) (in blue) and Im(f*g) (in orange) the following:
[image]

Now, looking at the edges of the imaginary part, we see there is a deviation from a zero value (in the region about +- 2000). However, from the convolution integral, if both f and g decay to 0 at infinity, the values of the convolution at the edges of the x grid should be zero, whereas here I observe that odd, kind of ripple. The problem is that such boundary effect affects another part of the calculation that depends on the obtained signal. I would like to know a way to circunvent this, while still having enough resolution in the middle region. The N_points parameter is an important one and needs to be kept not too high for the overall calculation to be efficient.

Comment: Your code doesn't suffer from boundary effects, it's a proper linear convolution, trimmed to first input's length; see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html).

Comment: But how does that explain the behaviour at the edge? If the signals would decay to 0 as x-> +- Infinity, then the result of the convolution at the edges should also give a signal with zero value; however I am observing these peaks, result of the fact that the tails are not exactly zero at my x_min, x_max, and that the window signal has a peak in its central part.

Comment: Convolving complex is trickier; share full code to reproduce the signal and convolutions so it's easier to look into.

Comment: I have updated the post, I hope this minimal code helps to see my problem here.

Comment: 3D arrays and involved maths to generate two complex signals, not really 'minimal'; remove everything that's not used in the illustrating example (or simplify example). From inspecting used slices in `F1` and `F4`, nothing's unusual, `F1` decays rather slowly, and the `full` convolution _does_ decay to zero; `same` trims the result to match `F1`'s length.

Comment: You mention the full convolution does decay to 0, which is what is expected, but how does that match with the original grid of points "x" ? Since the output is of dimension 2*Npoints - 1, and the "x" grid only has N_points; what I want is the value of the integral at exactly those "x" points.

Comment: There's no guarantee for trimmed convolution to mimic full convolution's behavior; what you get _is_ "value of integral at exactly those x points". If you seek trimmed to be zero at edges, convolve with something that decays to zero faster.

Comment: I should clarify I meant there are no _circular convolution_-related boundary effects; linear conv has its own 'artifacts', but the fast decay idea applies. Good material [here](https://www.dspguide.com/CH6.PDF)